# it was compiled with a higher Java version than the one used -- Anroid

Tags: java, react-native, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have one application in android, i changed one library but it is showing the next error when i try to compile it

> > Task :app:transformClassesWithDynatraceTransformerForColombiaDebug FAILED Execution failed for task
> > ':app:transformClassesWithDynatraceTransformerForColombiaDebug'.
> > com.dynatrace.tools.android.InstrumentationException: Unable to instrument class
> > com.co.demo.sdk.android.webview.WebViewException$Companion because it
> > was compiled with a higher Java version than the one used for this
> > build. Please adapt your JRE accordingly to
> > https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/dynatrace-android-gradle-plugin-overview#requirements
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

My java version is

> Test@Local Dummy % java -version openjdk version "11.0.14.1"
> 2022-02-08 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.14.10.1
> (build 11.0.14.1+10-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
> Corretto-11.0.14.10.1 (build 11.0.14.1+10-LTS, mixed mode)

**The full error is**

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> com/co/sdk/android/test/exception/BackendException has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> com/co/sdk/android/test/exception/BackendException has been compiled
> by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version
> 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0    at
> com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.transform.instrumentor.InstructionInstrumentor.transformMethod(InstructionInstrumentor.java:77)
> at
> com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.transform.DefaultSubTransformer.transformMethod(DefaultSubTransformer.java:77)
> at
> com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.Instrumentor.transform0(Instrumentor.java:150)
> at
> com.dynatrace.android.instrumentation.Instrumentor.instrument(Instrumentor.java:104)
> at
> com.dynatrace.tools.android.transformation.InstrumentedBuild.transformContent(InstrumentedBuild.java:75)
> ... 134 more

Comment: Java is backward compatible but not forward compatible. You can't embed a library compiled in Java X and run the code with Java X-1 since there is no guarantee that the JRE X-1 understands the bytecode produced by the JRE X (while the other way round is always guaranteed)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ which is the solution in this case ?

Comment: To use a version of the library which is compatible with your JDK. External libraries usually provide a table of compatibilities (for example version xxx is compatible with JDK 11, version yyy with JDK 16 and so on)

Comment: [java 11 is version 55](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/950837), so my guess is somehow java 8 is getting picked up in your environment.